# Probability mass function of a, random variable considered on a probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

This is a proof that I developed for myself and I'm asking whether it is true.

Let X be a random variable that take integer values with probability mass function of P<sub>X</sub>(x). Let Y be a random variable that also take integer values.

Consider the below discrete random variable,

P<sub>X</sub>(Y)

We can describe this as follows,

Let `b` be an event such that Y(`b`) = z. The random variable P<sub>X</sub>(Y) describes the probability of event `a`  that corresponds to X(`a`) = z.

Now I tried to solve the probability mass function of P<sub>X</sub>(Y) for a given value.

Which is P<sub>P<sub>X</sub>(Y)</sub>(0.1).

My argument is, P<sub>P<sub>X</sub>(Y)</sub>(0.1) tells us to find the probability of such event `c`.

To find this event `c`, I thought it as the event which gave P<sub>X</sub>(Y) = 0.1. That means there is such an event `b` in Y's sample space and an event `a` in X's sample such that X(`a`) = Y(`b`). And P(`a`) = 0.1.

Therefore the event that gave the random variable 0.1 value is `a`. Hence `c` = `a`.

Therefore P<sub>P<sub>X</sub>(Y)</sub>(0.1) = 0.1.

Am I correct. If you can point out what I've done is correct or wrong I'm very glad.

Comment: What does $P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$ mean ? The subscript of $P$ should be a random variable w.r.t which you're computing the probability.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan A function of a random variables is a random variable. Since X and Y are random variables, $${P_X(Y)}$$
is also a random variable. Hence
$$P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$$
is the PMF of that random variable which has a value of 0.1.

Comment: I'm sorry are you trying to compute, the Probability that "the probability is 0.1" ?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan No I'm trying to compute the probability of  the event, which gives the above random variable a value of 0.1. Since I explained a random variable can be made of two other random variables.

Comment: Just to confirm, the Random Variable you're constructing is itself a probability right ?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan When we consider a particular event, the constructed random variable gives a numerical probability value. But we can compute a probability for a random variable value. Is it correct?

Comment: oh alright, then lemme ask this way...The Random Variable you're constructing is already a PMF right ?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Yeah it is already a PMF you are correct at that point. My argument in the question is that's why it gave me the same answer for $$P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$$ as 0.1. In the both ways this calculates the same event's probability.

Comment: That is absolutely correct...You're calculating the probability that the PMF takes some value $c$ therefore you're calculating the probability of the same set of events that which resulted into PMF taking the value $c$. Therefore the probability must be $c$.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Thanks for the clarification!:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through some further thinking on the problem and found an elegant solution.

Given above random variables $X$ and $Y$.
Since ${P_X(Y)}$ is a random variable, it has a PMF. So my interpretation for $P_ X(Y)$ is follows.

Let $b$ be an event s.t $Y(b) = z$, for this event $P_ X(Y)$ takes the value of $P(a)$, where $a$ is an event in $X$'s sample space s.t $X(a) = z$

Now lets consider the PMF of $P_ X(Y)$, which is $P_{P_X(Y)}$.

If we calculate the $P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$, my argument is,

$P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$ tells us to find the probability of such event $c$.

To find this event $c$, I thought it as the event which gave $P_ X(Y)$ = 0.1. That means there is such an event $a$ in $X$'s sample space and $P(a) = 0.1$. This event $a$ is found  for $P_ X(Y(b))$ such that $X(a) = Y(b)$ for an event $b$ in $Y$'s sample space.
Therefore the event of interest that gave the random variable a value of 0.1, is $b$. Hence $c = b$.

Therefore $P_{P_X(Y)}(0.1)$= $P(b)$.